How to record audio with ffmpeg with Python on Ubuntu 22.04?
I encountered the problem of recording output audio on Ubuntu with Python. I want to record the output sound from the browser. I used USB Headphone as the output device, then record sounded with ffmpeg.
pactl list short sources output:
0. alsa_output.usb-0c76_USB_PnP_Audio_Device-00.analog-stereo.monitor  module-alsa-card.c      s16le 2ch 48000Hz       SUSPENDED
1. alsa_input.usb-0c76_USB_PnP_Audio_Device-00.mono-fallback  module-alsa-card.c      s16le 1ch 48000Hz       SUSPENDED 
2. alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.iec958-stereo.monitor     module-alsa-card.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED

When I run the following command on Ubuntu, it records audio successfully:
ffmpeg -f pulse -i alsa_output.usb-0c76_USB_PnP_Audio_Device-00.analog-stereo.monitor -t 10 output.wav


However, when I executed the command in the Python project, this error is reported:
alsa_output.usb-0c76_USB_PnP_Audio_Device-00.analog-stereo.monitor: Operation not permitted

or if using another output:
alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.iec958-stereo.monitor: Operation not permitted



Please edit the question and add the version of Ubuntu.

ffmpeg -hide_banner -f pulse -i default ...

@DavidDE Yes, i have added version Ubuntu to the question. It's 22.04

@JayCravens
I have try it, but i still get error:
default: Operation not permitted

@DinhChu Try running it with sudo.  What happens then?
